# Inheritance and Multiple Collaborators

Tags: java, generics, inheritance

I have several Java interfaces/ABCs/classes:

```
public abstract class Target {
    public abstract void fire(Load load);
}

public class HttpTarget extends Target {
    @Override
    public void fire(Load load) {
        // ...
    }
}

public interface Load {
    // ...
}

public class HttpLoad implements Load {
    // ...
}

// Inside a driver
Target target = testSuite.getTarget();
Load load = testSuite.getLoad();

target.fire(load);
```

So essentially a `Target` can `fire()` a `Load`. My main app `Driver` doesn't care about what kind of `Target` is returned by `getTarget()`, or what kind of `Load` is returned by `getLoad()`. It's job is to make sure that a load is fired.

I'd like to change the `fire()` method definition inside `HttpTarget` to:

```
@Override
public void fire(HttpLoad httpLoad) {
    // ...
}
```

However when I do that, Java complains that the method override doesn't match the definition provided by its parent `Target` class (as `Load` and `HttpLoad` are two different things).

What's the solution here? Generics? Abstract factories? **Ultimately, I want to be able to enforce that `HttpTarget`'s `fire()` method can only accept `HttpLoad`s, but still be compatible with the `Driver` code.** Can someone provide a code example? Thanks in advance!

Comment: did you try removing the @Override annotation?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Yes, you would need generics:

```
public abstract class Target<L extends Load> {
    public abstract void fire(L load);
}

public class HttpTarget extends Target<HttpLoad> {
    @Override
    public void fire(HttpLoad load) {
        ...
    }
}

public interface TestSuite<L extends Load> { // or class
    L getLoad();
    Target<L> getTarget();
}

public class HttpTestSuite implements TestSuite<HttpLoad> {
    @Override
    public HttpLoad getLoad() {
        ...
    }

    @Override
    public Target<HttpLoad> getTarget() {
        return new HttpTarget();
    }
}
```

The reason Java refuses to compile your HttpTarget class is because it doesn't override the Target's `fire(Load)` method. Indeed, a Target, by contract is supposed to accept any kind of Load as argument. And the `HttpTarget`'s `fire()` method only accepts instances of HttpLoad, and thus breaks the Liskov principle. Generics are the solution to this problem.

Comment: +1 Nice! Is there a way to declare just the method as generic and override it to accept only a subclass?

Answer (score 0):

You will have to use generics and even then it is not exactly what you want.

```
public interface Load<T extends Load> {

    public void someMethod();

}

public class HttpLoad implements Load<HttpLoad> {

    @Override
    public void someMethod() {
        System.out.println("Http Load");
                ...
    }

}

public abstract class Target<T extends Load> {

    public abstract void fire(Load<T> load);


}

public class HttpTarget extends Target<HttpLoad> {

    @Override
    public void fire(Load<HttpLoad> load) {
        load.someMethod();

    }

}
```

Now if you write

```
Target<HttpLoad> httpTarget = new HttpTarget();
Load<HttpLoad> httpLoad = new HttpLoad();
Load<OtherLoad> otherLoad = new OtherLoad();
Load otherLoad2 = new OtherLoad();

httpTarget.fire(httpLoad);
httpTarget.fire(otherLoad); // this doesn't compile
httpTarget.fire(otherLoad2) // this how ever compiles
```