# OOP: How to write families of classes to work together?

Tags: java, oop, generics

Yesterday I asked [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12513329/inheritance-and-multiple-collaborators) question, and the solution posted by @JB Nizet worked perfectly. However, that answer, as well as a few other answers/comments got me thinking in a different direction altogether.

Essentially, I have the following classes:

- `Load`
- `HttpLoad extends Load`
- `Target`
- `HttpTarget extends Target`
- `Controller`

The `Controller`'s job is to `Target::fire()` a `Load`, and doesn't care which `Target` is firing which `Load`:

```
// Inside Controller.java
Target target = getTarget();
Load load = getLoad();

target.fire(load);
```

However, I might some day write a `FtpLoad extends Load`, and I don't want to be able to fire a `FtpLoad` at an `HttpTarget`. So the essence of the above-referenced question was **how do I do this**, to which, the answer was *generics*.

However, as the answerer pointed out, this solution is a violation of the Liksov Substitution Principle. Other answerer/commenters seemed to indicate that what I was doing wasn't necessarily good OOP practices.

So now I'm asking: **how do I expose an API so that the `Controller` can be `Load`- and `Target`-agnostic, but still enforce that the proper `Load` subclass is fired on the proper `Target` type, all without violating Liskov Substitution?**

And, if this is impossible to do (without violating Liskov), then what is the normal approach to a problem like this? Thanks in advance!

Comment: I call that inheritance-for-templating.  Using inheritance because things have a lot of common functionality/attributes but there isn't actually any polymorphic relationship.  The "normal" approach is to do it anyway and have clunky APIs full of "supports" methods or similar :)  An alternative is encapsulation and multiple dispatch, but people find that hard to understand.

Comment: Rule of thumb: overridden methods are almost always violations of Liskov substitutability, because they change the behavior of the subtype when used in place of the supertype.

Comment: Changing behaviour does not violate the principle.  Narrowing pre-conditions or widening post-conditions does.  Which in general does happen when inheritance is used for framework templating tasks rather than modelling polymorphic relationships.

Comment: I find it confusing that `Targets` are doing the firing. I think of targets as things that get fired _at_.

Comment: @Affe Good catch, it looks like my understanding of the LSP was based on the one-sentence synopsis: "What is wanted here is something like the following substitution property: If for each object o1 of type S there is an object o2 of type T such that for all programs P defined in terms of T, the behavior of P is unchanged when o1 is substituted for o2 then S is a subtype of T." - Barbara Liskov, Data Abstraction and Hierarchy, SIGPLAN Notices, 23,5 (May, 1988).

Comment: Thanks @Affe (+1) - can you please provide an example of what you mean by both your suggestions (*support-method-heavy API* and *encapsulation with multiple dispatch*)? The only decent article of multidispatch I could find was [here](http://www.cs.ucla.edu/~todd/research/pub.php?id=oopsla00) and I couldn't make much sense of it. Thanks again!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The easy way is to do some checking in your code to make sure the classes match up. You can use the `instanceof` keyword to check if it's the correct class.

Answer (score 1):

If `HttpTarget.fire` allows any `Load` as parameter, it is its job to check if it can `fire` this `Load`. So either the `Controller` calls `fire` blindly, and `fire` checks if the given target can fire that kind of `Load` (with `instanceof`), or you include a function `canFire` in every `target` that implements this check and is called by the `Controller`.

Answer (score 1):

The typing problem here is that **`HttpTarget` is not a Liskov subtype of `Target`**, because *semantically* it is attempting to strengthen the preconditions of `Target#fire(Load)` to require the `Load` be `HttpLoad`.

This can be trivially repaired by declaring `Target#fire(Load) throws IncompatibleLoadException` and having a default implementation that always throws, forcing `Controller` to deal with the fact that a mismatched `Load` can be passed in.

Answer (score 0):

Best is to implement abstract class or an interface and use instanceof as mentioned before.

With an abstract class:

```
public abstract class TargetLoad {
    public abstract void fire(TargetLoad i);
}

public class Load extends TargetLoad {
    @Override
    public void fire(TargetLoad i) {
        if (i instanceof Target) return;
        // do fire stuff
    }
}

public class Target extends TargetLoad {
    @Override
    public void fire(TargetLoad i) {
        if (i instanceof Load) return;
        // do fire stuff
    }
}
```

with an interface:

```
public interface TargetLoad {
    public void fire(TargetLoad i);
}

public class Load implements TargetLoad {
    @Override
    public void fire(TargetLoad i) {
        if (i instanceof Target) return;
        // do fire stuff
    }
}

public class Target implements TargetLoad {
    @Override
    public void fire(TargetLoad i) {
        if (i instanceof Load) return;
        // do fire stuff
    }
}
```

In your Controller you refer to your objects as TargetLoad

```
TargetLoad target = getTarget();
TargetLoad load = getLoad();

target.fire(load);
load.fire(target);
load.fire(load);     //this will do nothing
target.fire(target); //this will do nothing
```

Answer (score 0):

I strongly disagree with the slew of answers recommending to use `instanceof`.  Well-written OOP code very rarely needs to use `instanceof`, and using `instanceof` will generally make your code awkward and difficult to maintain.  As a general rule, avoid `instanceof` if at all possible.

The previous question you referred to provided a solution using generics.  I'm not sure you left the generics code out of your question here; go back to your generic code.  Now, add the following method to your driver.

```
private <L extends Load> void runSuite(TestSuite<L> suite) {
  Target<L> target = testSuite.getTarget();
  L load = testSuite.getLoad();
  target.fire(load);
}
```